# Probability that sum of integer reciprocals is larger than a fixed number.

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

Suppose $n$ numbers are drawn independently from the list of $m$ integers $\{1,2,3,\ldots ,m\}$ uniformly at random. Denote these $n$ picks as $x_1,x_2,\ldots x_n$. Note that $n\geq m$ is possible. Fix a positive integer $C$. I am trying to determine the probability that $$\sum_{i = 1}^{n} \frac{1}{x_n}\geq C.$$

However I am not really sure where to start as I have not done much work with probability before.

Is there some way to get such a probability?

Comment: Have you tried simulating it? There are some edge cases it seems it can be easy to formulate.

Comment: Did you mean to include values starting at $0$?

Comment: Woops no that is an error.

Comment: It is now fixed

Comment: $P(S<C|n,m,C)$ might be a notation for that probability yes.  So given the two integers $n$ and $m$ and a real number $C$, what is the probability that the sum $S$, which you've indicated above is less than or equal to $C$?

Comment: you'd start for solving for the distribution $P(S)$ and then taking the subset of that for which $S<C$

Comment: I'd go with
$$S=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{x_n}=\sum\limits_{i=1}^m \frac{n_i}{i}$$
where $n_i \geq0$,$n_i \in\mathbb{N}$ and $\sum\limits_{i=1}^m n_i=n$. Then 
$$P(S\geq C) = 1 - P(S<C)$$
And check all the possible $(n_i)_{i=1}^m$ for which $S<C$. A small program (e.g.) in Python to check a few values, see if there is a patter.

Comment: so $n_i$ is the number of times integer $i$ (which is less than or equal to $m$) is selected ....

Comment: @phdmba7of12 yep, indeed ... the number of all $(n_i)_{i=1}^m$ can be calculated with stars-and-bars.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is anything except counting cases or simulation for small $n$.  For large $n$ you can use the normal approximation, but I suspect $n$ has to be pretty large for that to work.  The average reciprocal is $\frac {H_m}m\approx \frac {\log m + \gamma}m$.  The problem is that the variance of your numbers is large.  The sum will be dominated by how many times you pick $1$ and $2$ because the reciprocals of all the high numbers are about the same and small.  The expected number of $1$s is $\frac nm$ with a standard deviation of about $\sqrt{\frac nm}$.

Comment: "with a variance of about $\sqrt{\frac nm}$" 
That should be the standard deviation, no ?

Comment: @leonbloy:  yes, that is right.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is actually more of a consideration than an answer, 
but wishfully it may be of some help.

We have $n$ [discrete uniform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_uniform_distribution) i.i.d. random variables $X_k$, ranging from $1$ to $m$, 
and we want to find the distribution of the sum of their inverse.

To the scope of finding an approximation for high values of $m$ and $n$,  we should go through 
the [Characteristic Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_%28probability_theory%29) of each variable $1/X_k$, exploiting the fact that the CF of
the sum will be the $n$-th power of the single CF. And after getting the global CF we can invert it to get the sought pdf.

The single CF is given by
$$
\eqalign{
  & \varphi _{1/X} (t) = E\left[ {e^{\,i\,t/X} } \right] = {1 \over m}\sum\limits_{k = 1}^m {e^{\,i\,t/k} }  =   \cr 
  &  = e^{\,i\,t} {1 \over m}\sum\limits_{k = 1}^m {e^{\, - i\,t\left( {k - 1} \right)/k} }  \cr} 
$$
and the matter comes to find a suitable approximation for the sum, or rather for its logarithm.

It might help
to approximate each variable with
a [continuous uniform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_%28continuous%29) one ranging, from $1/2$ to $m+1/2$ and with probability density 
of $1/m$.
Geometrically that means to approximate a discrete hystogram of $m$ bars of height $1/m$
with $m$ vertical bands (rectangles) of width $1$ and height $1/m$, centered 
around each integral point.

Then the [Characteristic Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_%28probability_theory%29) of each continuous variable $1/X_k$ would be
$$
\eqalign{
  & \varphi _{1/X} (t) = E\left[ {e^{\,i\,t/X} } \right] = {1 \over m}\int_{\;x = 1}^{\,m} {e^{\,i\,t/x} dx}  =   \cr 
  &  = {1 \over m}\left( {\int_{\;x = 1}^{\,m} {\cos \left( {{t \over x}} \right)dx}  + i\int_{\;x = 1}^{\,m} {\sin \left( {{t \over x}} \right)dx} } \right) \cr} 
$$